# mysql complicated inner join on many to many

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have 7 tables `db_category`, `db_city`, `db_locality`, `db_shop`, `db_shop_locality`, `db_shop_recommended`, `db_shop_views`.

db_category

```
category_id    category_name    publish
    1             Apparel          1
```

db_city

```
city_id        city_name        publish
   1           bangalore           1
```

db_locality

```
locality_id     locality_name     publish
    1            kalyan nagar       1
    2            Madiwala           1
```

db_shop

```
shop_id   category_id   city_id   locality_id   shop_name   publish
   1          1            1          1           name         1
   2          1            1          2           name1        1
   3          1            1          1           name2        1
   4          1            1          1           name3        1
```

db_shop_recommended

```
recommended_id     category_id     shop_id    priority    publish
     1                 1             1           1           1
     2                 1             2           2           1
```

db_shop_views

```
views_id    shop_id    ip_addr    publish
    1          1      127.0.0.1      1
    2          2        ::1          1
    3          4      127.0.0.1      1
    4          4        ::1          1
    5          3        ::1          1
```

I want to join all the above tables. And the conditions for the join are,

1. display all the rows from `db_shop` when `publish=1` and join `db_category`, `db_city` and `db_locality` with `db_shop`
2. in `db_shop_recommended` who's `priority=1` comes first and so on.
3. and `shop_id` not in `db_shop_recommended`, count `shop_id` not in `db_shop_recommended` from `db_shop_views` who's `shop_id` got more views.

My result should looks like below,

```
shop_id   category_name   city_name   locality_name   shop_name
   1         Apparel      bangalore   kalyan nagar     name (result based on `db_shop_recommended` who's priority is more) 
   2         Apparel      bangalore     Madiwala       name1 (result based on `db_shop_recommended` who's priority is more) 
   4         Apparel      bangalore   kalyan nagar     name4 (result based on `db_shop_views` who's view count is more) 
   3         Apparel      bangalore   kalyan nagar     name3 (result based on `db_shop_views`)
```

I have no idea how to join and count the views. Is it possible to join in above method.

Comment: sqlfiddle for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of searching. Finally i got the answer.

`SELECT DISTINCT s.shop_id, c.city_name, l.locality_name, ca.category_name, s.shop_name, s.shop_logo, s.cart_url, s.shop_about FROM db_shop s INNER JOIN db_city c ON c.city_id = s.city_id INNER JOIN db_category ca ON ca.category_id = s.category_id INNER JOIN db_locality l ON l.locality_id = s.locality_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM db_shop_recommended r ORDER BY r.priority ASC) r1 ON s.shop_id = r1.shop_id LEFT JOIN (select distinct g.shop_id, g.cnt from (select distinct shop_id, count(shop_id) cnt from db_shop_views group by shop_id) g inner join (select max(s.cnt) max_cnt from(select distinct shop_id, count(shop_id) cnt from db_shop_views group by shop_id) s) m on m.max_cnt = g.cnt) v ON s.shop_id = v.shop_id WHERE s.publish = 1`